# Библиотека распаковки архивов 7z на Python

Tags: python, 7z, archive

Подскажите библиотеку для создания и распаковки 7zip архивов для python. С горем пополам смог открыть архив с помощью py7zlib, но создать архив не получается.

Comment: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylzma

Comment: Спасибо, видел, но я не нашел доков\примеров, как создавать архив.

Comment: @moden https://github.com/fancycode/pylzma/blob/master/tests/test_pylzma.py

Comment: Неправильный ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если это дело под linux то я бы не парился бы а использовал стандартные средства, то есть вызывал бы внешнюю утилиту 7zip через модуль commands.